# SQL Server : set all column aliases in a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's a bit of a long and convoluted story why I need to do this, but I will be getting a query string which I will then be executing with this code

```
EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL
```

I need to set the aliases of all the columns to "value".  There could be a variable number of columns in the queries that are being passed in, and they could be all sorts of data types, for example

```
SELECT 
    Company, AddressNo, Address1, Town, County, Postcode 
FROM Customers

SELECT 
    OrderNo, OrderType, CustomerNo, DeliveryNo, OrderDate 
FROM Orders
```

Is this possible and relatively simple to do, or will I need to get the aliases included in the SQL queries (it would be easier not to do this, if it can be avoided and done when we process the query)

---Edit---
As an example, the output from the first query would be

```
Company   AddressNo Address1     Town   County   Postcode
--------- --------- ------------ ------ -------- --------
Dave Inc  12345     1 Main Road  Harlow Essex    HA1 1AA
AA Tyres  12234     5 Main Road  Epping Essex    EP1 1PP
```

I want it to be

```
value     value     value        value  value    value
--------- --------- ------------ ------ -------- --------
Dave Inc  12345     1 Main Road  Harlow Essex    HA1 1AA
AA Tyres  12234     5 Main Road  Epping Essex    EP1 1PP
```

So each of the column has an alias of "value"

I could do this with

```
SELECT 
    Company AS 'value', AddressNo AS 'value', Address1 AS 'value', Town AS 'value', County AS 'value', Postcode AS 'value' 
FROM Customers
```

but it would be better (it would save additional complexity in other steps in the process chain) if we didn't have to manually alias each column in the SQL we're feeding in to this section of the process.

Regarding the XY problem, this is a tiny section in a very large process chain, it would take pages to explain the whole process in detail - in essence, we're taking code out of our database triggers and putting it into a dynamic procedure; then we will have frontends that users will access to "edit" the SQL statements that are called by the triggers and these will then dynamically feed the results out into other systems.  It works if we manually alias the SQL going in, but it would be neater if there was a way we could feed clean SQL into the process and then apply the aliases when the SQL is processed - it would keep us DRY, to start with.

Comment: Please give us an example because it is not realy clear what do you want to acomplish

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: `columns to "value" ` please share some sample what you want to achieve say for example if company is 'C1' then you want column name as C1.. but what if there are two or more rows being selected with different company names?

Comment: When you create the query text dynamically then what is the problem? You can create whatever alias you need within the query text,

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal this doesn't really preserve DRY as it relies on all your processes that are creating the input SQL to alias the columns the same way.  If we can do it at this stage, then if we need to change the alias format, in the future, we only need to change this code and not each input process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand at all what you are trying to accomplish, but I believe the answer is no: there is no built-in way how to globally predefine or override column aliases for ad hoc queries. You will need to code it yourself.